# removing whitespace in math expression

Tags: math-mode

Sometimes, one doesn't want whitespace between tokens of a math expression, and how can one remove the whitespace? For example, `$ foo-bar $` displays as `foo - bar`, but `foo-bar` is prefered.

Comment: In this short example, the answer is straight-forward: `-` is interpreted as a binary operator, which has space around it. If you want to avoid such space, use `{-}`. But if you're using text in this way, why not just write `foo-bar` outside math mode?

Comment: @Werner: or `\mathord{-}`

Comment: Is your `foo-bar` the name of a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$a-b$ and $a{-}b$ and $a\!-\!b$ and $a\!\!-\!\!b$
\end{document}
```

[image]